# Doctrine join a table with two

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

**Good morning**, as seen in the image below, I have some tables linked.

[image: EER]

Using Doctrine *(in Symfony2)* I'm trying to get an **array of Objects Issue** which itself contains all *IssueMessages* and *IssueStatusChanged* objects but can not.

I have no idea how I can do to **join** two tables *(IssueMessage and IssueStatusChanged)* to through their identifiers.

The **most we've done** is get all Issue with an account of the messages that have:

```
$dql = 'SELECT x, COUNT(im.id) FROM PanelBundle:Issue x LEFT JOIN PanelBundle:IssueMessages im WITH x.id = im.idIssue';
```

**Does anyone could give me a hand?**

**THANKS!**

Comment: do you have the relationship setup properly? I know youve posted the image (very helpful) but are you sure your mappings validate?

Comment: @DevDonkey Yeah, I just checked. `TABLE: issue_change_status COLUMN_NAME: id_issue, CONSTRAINT_NAME: FK_issueChangeStatus.idIssue_issue.id, REFERENCE_TABLE_NAME: issue, REFERENCE_COLUMN_NAME: id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [assication mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html); this will have Doctrine manage all the joins for you.

Once in place, `$issue` will always have the other associated models available automatically without you having to worry about joins.

For the example below (assuming you use annotation), to get messages for an issue just get the issue objects and then use `$issue->getMessages();`.

```
<?php

/** @Entity */
class issue
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    // ...

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="issueMessages", mappedBy="issue")
     */
    private $messages;

    // ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->messages = new Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/** @Entity */
class issueMessages
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="issue", inversedBy="messages")
     * @JoinColumn(name="issue_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $issue;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, I've been reading about and Mapping Association have done something very similar to your example, but when I load all data from the Issue, the field messages is *null*. Is it necessary to declare the OneToMany in Issue Messages? You do not have to touch any of the ORM XML? Thx :)

Comment: Without seeing the code I couldn't say. But beware, something that caught me out early on is that if you must initialise an associated (aka proxy) object; for example by querying it first with `$issue->getMessages();`. If you dump before this, you will always get `null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
If you using yml format for schema orm files than
first you need to write schema and mention oneToMany, manyToOne relationship with table fields & generate entity, repository class.

Than you can use join with two or more tables as below example:
Example of repository class file function:
----------------------------------------------------
public function getReportInfo($idUserDetail)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('UR')
        ->select("UR.report_period_start_date, UR.report_period_end_date")
        ->leftJoin('UR.UserReportDetail', 'URD')
        ->andWhere('UR.id_user_detail = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->orderBy('UR.report_year', 'DESC')         
        ->addOrderBy('UR.report_month', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(1);

    $resultArray = $query->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

    return $resultArray;
}

You can call this function from controller action as below:
-------------------------------------------------------------
public function getUserDetailAction($idUserDetail)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $userDetail = $em->getRepository(
        'DemoBundle:UserDetail')
        ->getReportInfo($idUserDetail);

    return $userDetail;
}

I hope this would be useful to you.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem reside in the DQL syntax (+ missing inverse relation?).

By writing this:

```
SELECT x, COUNT(im.id) FROM PanelBundle:Issue x
LEFT JOIN PanelBundle:IssueMessages im WITH x.id = im.idIssue
```

you are joining two "random" table based on the condition provided in the WITH clause. This should usually be ok, but it may confuse the Hydrator component.

In your case you should configure the `OneToMany` side of the relation in `Issue` entity, then write something like this:

```
SELECT x, COUNT(im.id) FROM PanelBundle:Issue x
LEFT JOIN x.issueMessages im
```

Hope it helps!